# How to display item from collection using Id in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have this collection:

```
    this.students = [
      { id: 1, courseId: 1, text: 'John' },
      { id: 2, courseId: 1, text: 'Andye' },
      { id: 3, courseId: 1, text: 'Inga' },
      { id: 4, courseId: 2, text: 'Jerry' }
    ];
```

I have this label:

```
            <div class="">
                <label class="control-label">Student Name: </label>
                <label class="control-label">"show student name"</label>
           </div>
```

I want to display for example student name with **Id = 3**,
in this label:

```
<label class="control-label">"show student name"</label>
```

What is elegant way to display text by Id from the collection in AngularJS?

Comment: You could have an `ng-repeat` like `ng-repeat="student in vm.students | filter: {id : 3}"`

Comment: Why do you have an array of students in the model if the goal is to display only one of them? There seems to be a larger design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most succinct way to achieve the desired result would be to define a method on the scope which returns whichever student you want by some criteria, in this case their `id`.

```
// controller.js
this.getStudentById = function(id) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
        if(this.students[i].id === id) {
            return this.students[i];
        }
    }
}

// template.html
<label class="control-label">{{getStudentById(<id>).name}}</label>
```

[@JB Nizet is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034907/how-to-display-item-from-collection-using-id-in-angularjs#comment51970863_32034907) however that if you only ever want a single student you might consider fetching only that student from your 'student service' rather than maintaining an array of students that are then filtered within your controller.